# Kotlin - How to run n coroutines and wait for first m results or timeout?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm attempting to write a function that will start n coroutines and wait until the first m to complete. Should m coroutines fail to complete within some timeout, then all coroutines/jobs are canceled. My initial implementation for this is shown below, however I feel it can be improved. My initial thought was to use a parent job to run all other jobs under so the parent job can be cancelled and cascade down to the remaining children. However, this results in a TimeoutCancellationException that has to be caught.

**How do I write a function to start n coroutines and wait until the first m to complete, or a timeout to occur before m coroutines can complete?**

```
private suspend fun queryAllHosts(
        queryFactories: List<(query: String, pageIndex: Int) -> String>
        , query: String
        , pageIndex: Int
        , maxSuccessfulHosts: Int
        , queryTimeout: Long
        , requestTimeout: Long
): ArrayList<QueryResult<ResultModel>> {
    val results = ArrayList<QueryResult<ResultModel>>()
    val rootJob = Job()

    try {
        withTimeout(queryTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
            queryFactories.map {
                async(parent = rootJob) {
                    val pagedResult = queryHost(
                            it
                            , query
                            , pageIndex
                            , requestTimeout
                    )

                    if (pagedResult.isSuccessful()) {
                        results.add(pagedResult)
                    }

                    if (results.size == maxSuccessfulHosts) {
                        rootJob.cancelAndJoin()
                        return@async
                    }
                }
            }.awaitAll()
        }
    } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        Log.w(Tag, "Query timed out, successful queries: ${results.size}")
    } catch (ignored: JobCancellationException) {
        // Ignored
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Log.w(Tag, "Unexpected exception", ex)
    }

    return results
}
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't have any luck with the previously accepted answer due to concurrent modification exceptions. Below is a slight tweak on the original answer to avoid the concurrent modification exception, however it fails to respect the ticker timeout.

**How does one avoid the concurrent modification exception and still respect the ticker timeout?**

```
suspend fun <T> List<Deferred<T>>.awaitCount(count: Int, timeoutMs: Long): List<T> {
    require(count <= size)

    val Tag = "DERP"

    val toAwait = HashSet<Deferred<T>>(this)
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    val ticker = ticker(timeoutMs)

    forEach { deferred ->
        deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
            if (!deferred.isCompletedExceptionally) {
                Log.d(Tag, "(Completed) Value: ${deferred.getCompleted()}")
            } else {
                Log.d(Tag, "(Completed) Exception: $it")
            }
        }
    }

    val processed = HashSet<Deferred<T>>()

    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        whileSelect {
            toAwait.minus(processed).forEach { deferred ->
                processed.add(deferred)
                deferred.onAwait {
                    toAwait.remove(deferred)
                    result.add(it)
                    result.size != count
                }
            }

            ticker.onReceive {
                toAwait.forEach { it.cancel() }
                false
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(Tag, "Elapsed time: $elapsedTime")

    return result
}
```

Deferred instances are created with the following code now:

```
private fun makeRequest(
        url: String
        , timeoutMs: Int
): Document? = try {
    Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(timeoutMs).get()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    null
}

private fun createAsyncRequests(
        queryFactories: List<(query: String, pageIndex: Int) -> String>
        , query: String
        , pageIndex: Int
        , timeoutMs: Int
): List<Deferred<QueryResult<TorrentResult>>> = queryFactories.map { queryFactory ->
    async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        try {
            val url = queryFactory(query, pageIndex)
            makeRequest(
                    url
                    , timeoutMs
            ).getQueryResult(pageIndex, url)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            QueryResult<TorrentResult>(state = QueryResult.State.ERROR)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Log below show supplied timoutMs of 2,000ms not being respected as timeout occurs at 11,861ms:

```
2018-09-13 22:39:00.307 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.315 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.454 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|1/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://indiapirate.com/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.455 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.456 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.470 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|2/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://superbay.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.471 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.472 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.479 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|3/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://superbay.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.480 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.480 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.481 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|4/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratebays.fi/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.481 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.482 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.500 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|5/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratebays.be/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.501 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.501 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.577 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|6/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratebay.nz/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.577 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.578 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.602 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|7/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratebay6.org/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.602 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.603 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.604 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|8/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepirateproxy.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.604 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.605 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.621 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|9/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://uktpb.net/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.621 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.622 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.694 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|10/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://proxyproxyproxy.net/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.695 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.695 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.712 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|11/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://fastpirate.link/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.713 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.713 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.868 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|12/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://freepirate.eu/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:00.869 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:00.869 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.480 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|13/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://pirate.tel/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:01.481 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.482 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.649 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|14/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratesbay.fi/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:01.649 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.650 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.780 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|15/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratepirate.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:01.781 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:01.782 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.131 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|16/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpbproxy.fi/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:03.132 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.132 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.250 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|17/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:03.251 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.253 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.296 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|18/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://freeproxy.click/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:03.296 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.297 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.441 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|19/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:03.442 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:03.443 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Starting deferred..
2018-09-13 22:39:04.826 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|20/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratepirate.net/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:04.868 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|21/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://proxyproxy.fi/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:05.325 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|22/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:05.926 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|23/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:06.002 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|24/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:06.117 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|25/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpbproxy.click/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:06.338 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|26/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:06.923 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|27/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepiratebay.red/search/hobbit+1977/0/7
2018-09-13 22:39:07.214 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|28/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepirateproxy.click/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:07.625 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|29/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepirateway.click/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:08.398 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|30/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:08.431 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|31/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://proxybay.blue/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:08.684 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|32/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://piratepiratepirate.org/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:09.033 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|33/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://unblocktpb.org/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:09.759 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|34/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:09.879 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|35/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpbunblock.net/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:09.961 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|36/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpbproxy.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:10.554 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|37/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:10.715 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|38/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://Piratebayproxy.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:10.855 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|39/50) Value: State: INVALID, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 0, Url: null
2018-09-13 22:39:11.014 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|40/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpb.fun/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:11.298 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|41/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepiratebayproxy.in/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:11.313 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|42/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://tpb.review/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:11.932 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|43/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://proxybay.life/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:12.166 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|44/50) Value: State: SUCCESS, Page: 0/0, Item Count: 14, Url: https://thepiratebayproxy.one/s/?q=hobbit+1977&page=0&orderby=99
2018-09-13 22:39:12.168 20475-20797/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: Elapsed time: 11861
2018-09-13 22:39:12.885 20475-20806/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|45/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@b129740
2018-09-13 22:39:13.437 20475-20807/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|46/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@c801679
2018-09-13 22:39:14.051 20475-20968/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|47/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@3f89fbe
2018-09-13 22:39:14.154 20475-20798/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|48/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@c7c181f
2018-09-13 22:39:14.658 20475-20886/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|49/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@729e76c
2018-09-13 22:39:17.334 20475-20802/com.masterwok.tpbsearchandroid D/DERP: (Completed|50/50) Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled normally; job=LazyDeferredCoroutine{Cancelled}@ae2a135
```

Updated code with logging (I removed the TimeoutException and returned false instead):

```
suspend fun <T> List<Deferred<T>>.awaitCount(
        count: Int
        , timeoutMs: Long
): List<T> {
    require(count <= size)

    val Tag = "DERP"

    val toAwait = CopyOnWriteArraySet<Deferred<T>>(this)
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    val ticket = ticker(timeoutMs)
    var completedCount = 0

    forEach { deferred ->
        deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
            completedCount++

            if (deferred.isCompletedExceptionally) {
                Log.d(Tag, "(Completed|$completedCount/$size) Exception: $it")
            } else {
                Log.d(Tag, "(Completed|$completedCount/$size) Value: ${deferred.getCompleted()}")
            }
        }
    }

    val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
        whileSelect {
            ticket.onReceive {
                toAwait.forEach { it.cancel() }
                false
            }

            toAwait.forEach { deferred ->
                Log.d(Tag, "Starting deferred..")
                deferred.onAwait {
                    toAwait.remove(deferred)
                    result.add(it)
                    result.size != count
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(Tag, "Elapsed time: $elapsedTime")

    return result
}
```

Comment: Two minor things: 1. use `launch` instead of `async` because it doesn't return anything. There's `joinAll` which you can use instead of `awaitAll`. 2. You don't need the `return@async` statement, it's the last line anyway.

Comment: Your code won't guarantee `maxSuccessfulHosts` as the upper bound on the number of results. While you're canceling the `rootJob`, other jobs may have already received their result and will add it to `results`.

Comment: If you need it as the exact upper bound, you should use `async { queryHost(...) }`, put all these `Deferred`s into a `mutableSet`, then `select` over all of them: `select { deferreds.forEach { it.onAwait { results.add(it.completedValue); deferreds -= it } } }` and rerun that `select` until timeout or until enough results have come in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be improved by avoiding using additional launched task and root job at all.

`kotlinx.coroutines` has `select` clause for such complex operators, which perfectly fits your use-case.
Moreover, it's easy to generalize:

```
suspend fun <T> List<Deferred<T>>.awaitCount(count: Int, timeoutMs: Long): List<T> {
    require(count <= size)

    val toAwait = CopyOnWriteArraySet<Deferred<T>>(this)
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    val ticket = ticker(timeoutMs)

    whileSelect {
        toAwait.forEach { deferred ->
            deferred.onAwait {
                toAwait.remove(deferred)
                result.add(it)
                result.size != count
            }
        }

        ticket.onReceive {
            val e = TimeoutException()
            toAwait.forEach { it.cancel(e) }
            throw e
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Then you can use it in `queryAllHosts`:

```
val queries = queryFactories.map { queryHost(...) }
return queries.awaitCount(maxSuccessfulHosts, queryTimeout)
```

You can adjust `awaitCount` in the way you want, e.g. specialize it for Retrofit and add `isSuccessful` check

Comment: Another small thing: `queryHost` is a `suspend fun`, not a `Deferred`-returning one. So can't avoid starting those coroutines: `queryFactories.map { async { queryHost(...) } }`

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Although this seems to result in a ConcurrentModificationException caused by removing the deferred from the ```toAwait``` HashSet.

Comment: @masterwok You're right, if the `deferred` is already completed by the time you execute `onAwait` on it, it will immediately go to the handler code and therefore try to modify `toAwait` while it's being iterated over. Honestly, there's a lot to be hated in this idiom, but it is a quite important idiom. Kotlin should add some first-class support to repeatedly select over a set of signals until they get exhausted.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've since moved to using an iterator and calling ```remove()``` in ```onAwait``` and that seems to have fixed the concurrent modification issue. However, I'm now having problems with the timeout ```onReceive``` never being invoked.

Comment: You can't use `iterator.remove()` because it causes the opposite problem: if it's not completed already, the iterator will already have moved to other items or be fully exhausted by the time the handler runs. This can explain your observed behavior: you removed the timer's entry in the set while handling `onAwait`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for you feedback. It seems the above code code still fails when using a lazy ```Deferred```?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "lazy `Deferred`". Yes, the code fails as explained above, and changing to `iterator.remove()` doesn't help.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik by lazy deferred I mean: ```async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { .. }```.  The asynchronous block won't be executed until ```onAwait```. I have updated the question above with how I'm avoiding the exception.

Comment: That doesn't fix it because you're executing the `select` in a loop and you may still stumble upon an already completed Deferred. One way to fix is iterating over an immutable snapshot of the set (a copy).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that was my intention of invoking ```toAwait.minus(processed)``` and then immediately adding the deferred into processed (before it's started). I was hoping the computed value on the next pass wouldn't contain any previously processed items. Shouldn't the ```ticker.onRecieve { .. }``` be invoked either way?

Comment: I've fixed `CME` in my answer. It can be further improved by using more accurate CoW pattern.

Comment: CoW is a concurrent design, I see it as overkill here, even though it does the job. A simple `toAwait.toList().forEach ...` is as effective.

Comment: @qwwdfsad thanks for updating your answer. However, I'm seeing that ```ticker.onReceive {...}``` is not invoked until ~16,000ms when passed a timeout of 2,000ms. I'm invoking this method on a ```List``` of about 50 ```Deferred``` instances. Do you know what would cause this?

Comment: @qwwdfsad I've added a slightly modified version of your answer to the question that includes logging and returns false rather than throwing an exception when a timeout occurs. The logs showing that the timeout occurs later than anticipated (expected ~2,000ms) have also been added to the question.

Comment: @qwwdfsad hmm.. never mind. The issue sees to stem from the ```Deferred``` instances I'm creating. When running your solution with 50 simple ```async { delay(10000) }``` it works as expected. Thanks you both for all your help!

Comment: Does the `onAwait` block and access of the `result` list require a Mutex/Lock here? I would have assumed that block can be called from the continuation of each coroutine, which might run on different threads. Is that wrong, and these blocks also use the ContinuationIntercepter facilities in order to get scheduled on the same thread?

Comment: @qwwdfsad Don't you need to cancel remaining deferred jobs when `result.size` becomes equal to `count`? And I believe `ticker` cancellation should also be considered