# How to find first desired result from kotlin coroutines Deferred<> (server)

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I’ve built a sharding library and i’m trying to add coroutine functionality to it. In the following snippet it returns the first `true` result that it finds:

```
override fun emailExists(email: String): Boolean {
    return runBlocking {
        shards
            .asyncAll { userDao.emailExists(email) }
            .map { it.await() }
            .firstOrNull { it }
    } ?: false
}
```

the shards.asyncAll method is:

```
fun <T> async(
    shardId: Long,
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Deferred<T> {
    return scope.async(context, start) {
        selectShard(shardId)
        block()
    }
}
fun <T> asyncAll(
    shardIds: Collection<Long> = this.shardIds,
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): List<Deferred<T>> {
    return shardIds.map { async(it, context, start, block) }
}
```

This works, but it consults the shards in order for their return, meaning if the first shard takes a very long time to return and it doesn't return `true` but the second shard returns immediately with a value of `true` we're still waiting as long as the first shard took to return. Is there a better way to wait on values for a collection of `Deferred<>`'s and process them in the order that they return so that I can exit as early as possible?

Comment: Ideally there would be a way without using Flow.

Comment: I specifically dont want to wait for all of them though.

Comment: Yes, sorry. `awaitAll` is good for reacting to the first error, but not for the first result. Seems there's no built-in `awaitAny` or `awaitFirst`, but there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192752/kotlin-how-to-run-n-coroutines-and-wait-for-first-m-results-or-timeout) that you can specialize to just one element.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/select-expression.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were to get your answer early, `runBlocking` would still wait for all the coroutines you started to complete before returning.

In order to run the kind of coroutine race you're looking for:

1. When the first task completes with **true**, it needs store that result and cancel the parent job of all the other tasks; and
2. The other tasks should properly abort when cancelled.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure Kotlin doesn't include a function that does this, so you have to do it yourself.  The easiest way is probably to have each throw an exception that indicates a true result.  You can then use `awaitAll` on the group, catch the exception, and extract the result.

Comment: But the first one to return might not be the result I'm looking for.

Comment: You would only throw the exception when it *is* the one you're looking for.  I'll adjust the text